# Как изменить цвет кнопки?

Tags: button, background

При добавлении кнопки, по умолчанию ставится фиолетовым. Не могу изменить цвет кнопки.  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Используй свойство backgroundTint.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное спасибо)